# Loop setting a variable in constructor

Tags: c#, hash, md5

I'm trying to set the variable `Senha` (password of my system) as a md5 hash of the original value.

```
public class Usuario
{
        public int ID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Nome { get; set; }
        [Required]
    public string Senha {
        get { return Senha; }
        set { Console.WriteLine("valor"+value );
            this.Senha = CalculateMD5Hash(value); }
    }

    public static String CalculateMD5Hash(String input) {

            // step 1, calculate MD5 hash from input
            MD5 md5 = MD5.Create();
            byte[] inputBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input);
            byte[] hash = md5.ComputeHash(inputBytes);
            // step 2, convert byte array to hex string
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < hash.Length; i++) {
                sb.Append(hash[i].ToString("X2"));
            }
            return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

But what is happening is that the class enter in a loop and makes hashes of the original hash.

E.g.: value = 123

value1 = 202CB962AC59075B964B07152D234B70 (hash of value)

value2 = D9840773233FA6B19FDE8CAF765402F5 (hash of value1)

How can I stop this loop and just trigger the function once ?

Comment: Where do you assign the values for value1 and value2

Comment: Since it seems to be a rarity these days, I should commend you on actually using the debugger to figure out a)it's going into a loop and b)what values are being calculated. Have an upvote. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your property is not defined correctly. Not only is your setter calling itself, your getter is calling itself too and will cause a stack overflow.

Instead, you need to provide a *backing field* to store the value of the property:

```
private string _senha;
public string Senha 
{
    get { return _senha; }
    set 
    { 
        Console.WriteLine("valor"+value );
        _senha = CalculateMD5Hash(value);
    }
}
```

---

By the way, since you specifically mention the word 'password', [using MD5 for passwords is a bad idea](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19906/is-md5-considered-insecure), so unless you're using this to access a legacy system you should really do it [the right way](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords).

Comment: The using of MD5 was just to use a hash. How the application is just learning, I think isn't a problem. But for a big and commercial application I use your tips.

Answer (score 2):

You need to define property with backing field in this case.

```
private string _senha;
public string Senha 
{
    get { return _senha; }
    set { Console.WriteLine("valor"+value );
          _senha = CalculateMD5Hash(value); 
        }
}
```